# Full path from flat array

Tags: javascript, arrays, path, tree

I have an array like this :

```
var folders = [
[1, 0, 'SAV'],
[2, 1, 'OLD'],
[3, 0, 'Working doc'],
[4, 3, 'User'],
[5, 0, 'Documentation'],
[6, 0, 'Specification'],
[7, 6, 'Components'],
[8, 6, 'test'],
[9, 8, 'subtest'],
[10, 9, 'subsubtest']];
```

The output should be

```
\SAV
\SAV\OLD
\Working doc
\Working doc\User ect...
```

I try to modify this php function

```
function show_menu($parent, $level, $array) {
    $html = "";
    foreach ($array as $node) {
        if ($parent === $node['parentid']) {
       for ($i = 0; $i < $level; $i++) {
            $html .= "-";
       }
       $html .= " " . $node['name'] . "<br />";
       $html .= show_menu($node['id'], ($node + 1), $array);
    }
}
return $html;
```

}

the purpose is to replace "-" by full path

Comment: You want the javascript solution or PHP solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build an object with identifier and their children relations and then create the pathes of the relations.

```js
function getPathes(relations) {
    const
        iter = path => ([id, value]) => {
            var p = path.concat(value);            
            result.push(p.join('\\'));
            (relations[id] || []).forEach(iter(p));
        },
        result = [];
    relations[0].forEach(iter(['']));
    return result;
}

var folders = [[1, 0, 'SAV'], [2, 1, 'OLD'], [3, 0, 'Working doc'], [4, 3, 'User'], [5, 0, 'Documentation'], [6, 0, 'Specification'], [7, 6, 'Components'], [8, 6, 'test'], [9, 8, 'subtest'], [10, 9, 'subsubtest']],
    relations = folders.reduce((r, [id, parent, value]) => {
        r[parent] = r[parent] || [];
        r[parent].push([id, value]);
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));

console.log(getPathes(relations));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this using **.map()**, **.find()** and **.replace()** methods, please see solution in JavaScript below...

```
var folders = [
  [1, 0, 'SAV'],
  [2, 1, 'OLD'],
  [3, 0, 'Working doc'],
  [4, 3, 'User'],
  [5, 0, 'Documentation'],
  [6, 0, 'Specification'],
  [7, 6, 'Components'],
  [8, 6, 'test'],
  [9, 8, 'subtest'],
  [10, 9, 'subsubtest']
];

function sortFolders(arr) {
  return arr.map(folderArr => {
    let parentFolder = arr.find(el => el[0] === folderArr[1])
    let string = (parentFolder) ?
      `/${parentFolder[2]}/${folderArr[2]}` :
      `/${folderArr[2]}`
    return string.replace(/\\/g, '\\');
  })
}

sortFolders(folders); // Returns an array with the expected output...
// [
//  '/SAV',
//  '/SAV/OLD',
//  '/Working doc',
//  '/Working doc/User',
//  '/Documentation',
//  '/Specification',
//  '/Specification/Components',
//  '/Specification/test',
//  '/test/subtest',
//  '/subtest/subsubtest'
// ]
```

Comment: Many Thanks for your answer, it works fine.
a little thing is missing for the last folder full path should be
/Specification/test/subtest and /Specification/test/subtest/subsubtest. 
I forgot to explain it in my question. If you can help me once again